# rails trouble with rspec and guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

I have `1200 rspec` context for my project.But test results differs time to time.Sometimes I run `bundle exec guard` and `1 tests fail` but also sometimes `15 tests fail` even if I did not change anything.Did you encounter problems like this ?

Comment: can you please run `bundle exec rspec ...`

Comment: That will depend on the tests what you have created and also database dependencies like truncation after the tests

Comment: Things like this can happen due to relative dependences. What tests are specifically failing?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any test depending on network, database state or some file that can be deleted?

Check for:

1. Database dependency
2. Network dependency (some service that can be off)
3. Other test dependency (RSpec eventually randomize tests execution order, I think that some test changes some state and breaks this specific test depending on execution order)